# Implementar um tamanho especifico para um div

Tags: javascript, css

Estou querendo que minha table tenha o mesmo tamanho da div que contém o meu iframe. Isso é possível? Se sim, o que estou fazendo de errado?

**obs:** Estou colocando no post as partes do meu código que afetam a div que contém o iframe e a minha implementação em javascript para setar o mesmo tamanho na table.

```js
var tableheight = document.getElementsByTagName("video-wrapper").offsetHeight;
  document.getElementsByTagName("table").style.height = tableWidth;
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}

tbody {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

tbody tr{
  margin: 2px solid white;
}

.video-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
}

.video-wrapper iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrap">
              <div class="video-wrapper"><iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/z9Ul9ccDOqE" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
            </div>
            
<table id="tableEsport">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Seria bom colocar o html da tabela

Comment: Não tinha colocado por que era extremamente simples, mas ta ae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código tem alguns erros:

Aqui você está querendo selecionar a classe pela tag que não existe e está usando o nome da classe, sem contar que é preciso especificar um índice, porque essa forma se seleção resulta em uma array:

```
var tableheight = document.getElementsByTagName("video-wrapper").offsetHeight;
```

O correto seria usar `getElementsByClassName`:

```
var tableheight = document.getElementsByClassName("video-wrapper")[0].offsetHeight;
```

Na outra linha o problema é parecido, só faltou especificar o índice e adicionar `"px"`, porque o CSS não reconhece `height` sem o tipo de valor (`px`, `em`, `vh`, `%` etc.). O correto seria:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].style.height = tableheight+"px";
```

Porém, há formas bem mais lúcidas de selecionar esses elementos, usando `querySelector`:

```
var tableheight = document.querySelector(".video-wrapper").offsetHeight;
document.querySelector("#tableEsport").style.height = tableheight+"px";
```

Assim você seleciona os elementos pela classe e pelo `id`.

> **Obs.:** ao selecionar uma classe com `querySelector`, é importante ter certeza que só existe 1 elemento com essa classe. Se houver mais
>   de 1, o `querySelector` só vai pegar o primeiro.

**Veja:**

```js
var tableheight = document.querySelector(".video-wrapper").offsetHeight;
document.querySelector("#tableEsport").style.height = tableheight+"px";
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}

tbody {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

tbody tr{
  margin: 2px solid white;
}

.video-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
}

.video-wrapper iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrap">
   <div class="video-wrapper"><iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/z9Ul9ccDOqE" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
            
<table id="tableEsport" bgcolor="#D51C1F">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```